# Vimscript: How to capitalize a specific character of matched text in a substitution?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm writing a Vim snippet that will take the current file's name and expand it into a class name, e.g.

If the current file name is: `some_awesome_class.foo` ... the snippet would expand to `class SomeAwesomeClass`

So far, I have:

`substitute(Filename(), '\(^.\|_\a\)', '\u&', 'g')`

.. but this only capitalizes the first letter, even though it correctly matches all the underscores. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to use the underscore as part of the search, but not have it be matched in the ampersand, i.e: it looks for `_\a` but only matches `\a`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
s/\v(^|_)(\a)/\u\2/g
```

Comment: You're welcome! `\v` is of course not necessary, but makes it cleaner.

Comment: Can you help me understand what \v does? It's pretty great that the vim docs actually refer to it as "very magic"

Comment: Basically, a great number of characters will now be magic by itself, without needing to escape. For example, `(` or `|` are non-magic by standard notation, i.e., they mean a parenthesis and pipe literally. But with very magic activated, they become magic and assume their escaped version role, as if you had typed `\(\|`. The help will tell you the rest in greater detail. Hope this helps! It confused me in the beginning too.

Comment: The non magic version of this command would be `s/\(^\|_\)\(\a\)/\u2/g`, one could get lost in the backslashes easily.

Comment: May I hijack your conversion and propose `:nnoremap / /\v`?

Comment: @romainl fantastic, I always wondered if there was a way to set very-magic as default. Seems like I missed the simple way :-) I'm adding it to my .vimrc right now, also with `:nnoremap ? ?\v`.

Answer (score 4):

You should exclude *the beginning of the line* and *underscore* from the match with `\zs`.

```
^.\|_\zs\a
```

This works, over here.

See `:help \zs` and `:help \ze`.

Comment: Awesome. This is easier to understand for me. It correctly capitalizes, but it still leaves the underscores in the final result.

Comment: @Tres I would go with this one, please move the correct answer mark to this answer. +1 romainl, I was trying to came up with a solution using `\zs` but ended up with lots of parenthesis…

Comment: I'll gladly do that, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the predicate to delete the underscores.

Comment: @Tres Mmm, actually I reached this problem some moments ago while creating a solution, then gave up and used parenthesis. I thought romainl had solved it when writing "This works, over here", actually this won't work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I somehow skipped the necessity to remove underscores.

Answer (score 1):

you need to separate them into word boundaries using ( ) and then camel Case each word.

```
:s/_\(.\)/\u\1/g
```

Try that..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is a good start, but it misses the first letter:

`someAwesomeClass`

I'm sure I can get it right by playing around a bit more with this approach.

Comment: Try `:s/\%(^\|_\)\(.\)/\u\1/g`

Comment: another way:
first add _ as word delim :set iskeyword-=_
then :%s/\(\<\)\(.\{1}\)/\u\2/g

Answer (score 1):

another way: first add _ as word delim

`:set iskeyword-=_` then

```
:%s/(\<)(.\{1})/\u\2/g
```